# Can we use "a night's good sleep" instead of "a good night's sleep"

Tags: grammar, adjective-order

I know that **" a good night's sleep"** is correct to use, but I wonder that if we were to switch the position of **"good"**, would it still be grammatically correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the interchangeability (depending on grammatical correctness) of *night* and *good* has not yet been proved in this case. However, I can imagine this short paraphrase coming up in a comic book or a Leslie Nielsen movie.

To illustrate the difference such a change can make, here's one for you:

> Your essay is an **outstanding work**.
>
> The **work outstanding** will in the long run overwhelm us physically.